# How to wrap child methods multiple times in an inheritance tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, design-patterns, frameworks

In a framework, I often want to provide a base class that the framework user sub classes. The base class provides controlled access to the base class. One way to accomplish this is to provide unimplemented methods with different names, for example by adding an underscore as prefix:

```
class Base:

    def method(self, arg):
        # ...
        result = self._method(arg)
        # ...
        return result

    def _method(self, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

However, this scheme only works for one level of inheritance. For more levels, the different method names make it hard to keep an overview of what's going on. Moreover, the framework user has to override different methods depending on the base class he chooses:

```
class Base:

    def method(self, arg):
        # ...
        result = self._method_sub(arg)
        # ...
        return result

    def _method_sub(self, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Intermediate(Base):

    def _method_sub(self, arg):
        # ...
        result = self._method_sub_sub(arg)
        # ...
        return result

    def _method_sub_sub(self, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Calling super methods does not help when the base method needs to access return values of the child method. I feel object orientation is slightly flawed, missing a `child` keyword that allows to forward calls to the child class. What solutions exist to solve this problem?

Comment: @FujiApple Let's say Python would have final methods. How would I allow child classes to implement part of them? The methods in my example are not really final. The child class provides behavior and the base classes wrap that. The base method may add behavior or range checks to the arguments and return values.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question - I _think_ I may know what you want but I'm really not sure: Have `Base.method()` wrap `Base.methodSub()` then have `Intermediate` provide a `methodSub()` implementation.  The parent `Base.method()` can then do any pre/post validation of the child implementation of `methodSub()`.  If that sounds right I can knock up an example, if not I'll bow out and let someone else figure it out :)

Comment: @FujiApple Exactly. However, both `Base` and `Intermediate` are abstract classes provided by the framework. For framework users to extend `Intermediate`, the class must provide a `Intermediate.methodSubSub()` and so on. That's not nice since the framework user needs to override different methods, depending on the base class he chooses.

Comment: I posted an answer below based on my (possibly still flawed) understanding of your question as it's to long to fit in the comments.  If I'm still missing the point let me know and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question focuses on different points where behavior extension in an intermediate class can happen. The intermediate class obviously shall refine the "*control*" part here.

## 1st Solution

Mostly this can be done the classical way by just overriding  the "safe" method - particularly when "*both Base and Intermediate are abstract classes provided by the framework*", things can be organized so. 
The final "silly" implementation class which does the spade work overrides the unsafe method.

Think of this example:

```
class DoublePositive:
    def double(self, x):
        assert x > 0
        return self._double(x)
    def _double(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError

class DoubleIntPositive(DoublePositive):
    def double(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, int)
        return DoublePositive.double(self, x)

class DoubleImplementation(DoubleIntPositive):
    def _double(self, x):
        return 2 * x
```

---

## 2nd Solution

**Calling virtual child class methods**, thus behavior extension at "inner" execution points in a non-classical manner, could be done by introspection in Python - by stepping down the class `__bases__` or method resolution order `__mro__` with a helper function.

Example:

```
def child_method(cls, meth, _scls=None):
    scls = _scls or meth.__self__.__class__
    for base in scls.__bases__:
        if base is cls:
            cmeth = getattr(scls, meth.__name__, None)
            if cmeth.__func__ is getattr(cls, meth.__name__, None).__func__:
                return child_method(scls, meth)  # next child
            if cmeth:
                return cmeth.__get__(meth.__self__)
    for base in scls.__bases__:
        r = child_method(cls, meth, base)  # next base
        if r is not None:
            return r
    if _scls is None:
        raise AttributeError("child method %r missing" % meth.__name__)    
    return None

class Base(object):
    def double(self, x):
        assert x > 0
        return Base._double(self, x)
    def _double(self, x):
        return child_method(Base, self._double)(x)        
class Inter(Base):
    def _double(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, float)
        return child_method(Inter, self._double)(x)
class Impl(Inter):
    def _double(self, x):
        return 2.0 * x
```

The helper function `child_method()` here is thus kind of opposite of Python's `super()`.

---

## 3rd solution

If calls should be chainable flexibly, things can be organized as a kind of handler chain explicitly. Think of `self.addHandler(self.__privmeth)` in the `__init__()` chain   - or even via a tricky meta class.  Study e.g. the urllib2 handler chains.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While your first solution is very clean, it means that `Intermediate` cannot extend the behavior of `Base`, it must fully replace it. Calling `super()` would not work since the base class calls the unimplemented user methods. Can you think of way to solve this? You second solution would actually work. I hoped to not work around inheritance, but if that's the only way, I'll accept that.

Comment: In the first solution the intermediate class (abstract as well) also "*extends*" the base behavior. Just at other points: "outside" by doing things before and after calling the base class. (`<BASECLASS>.double()` is just the explicit `super()` call here) While the child method call solution via the introspection helper function extends at other points: "inside".
Both solutions plus the option to provide a default implementation in the intermediate class, could also be mixed in the intermediate class: when it overrides both, the safe and unsafe method. So it can extend behavior at 4 points.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and update of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Does this give you what you want?

```
import abc

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def calculate(self):
        result = self.doCalculate()
        if 3 < result < 7: # do whatever validation you want
            return result
        else:
            raise ValueError()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def doCalculate(self):
        pass

class Intermediate(Base):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

class Leaf(Intermediate):
    def doCalculate(self):
        return 5

leaf = Leaf()
print leaf.calculate()
```

Comment: is it anything like builder or abstract factory design pattern ?

Comment: I'd say it is closest to the [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) GoF pattern

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much the solution. Since the parent method can't acquire the child methods return value, just delegate that to another method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still missing the point though. Both `Base` and `Intermediate` need the return value of their respective child method.